# Using TFS 2013 with the Agile template is it possible to get a story point total for a future sprint?

Tags: tfs, agile

In the web client for TFS 2013 on premise, there doesn't seem to be any way to see a story point total for a sprint.

In the overall backlog, under Stories, it shows a simple bar graph with story point history for previous sprints. What we need to know though is how many story points we've added to the current sprint to aid us in sprint planning. We can sum the story points manually, or export them to Excel, or create a grease monkey script, but it seems like this is a fundamental feature. Are we just missing this?

Comment: Sound incredibly reasonable request, but I don't think it's in the product right now. I suggest filing a request on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Comment: I submitted a request, any votes would be appreciated: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5509980-display-sum-of-story-points-in-a-sprint-agile-te